# How to access form elements in Controller in Yii

Tags: php, yii

How can I access the elements of my view in controller. lets I have a field name 'type' in my form field and I want to access the value of that field in my controller class. How can I achieve that.
I saw where we are fetching all attributes

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Alerts'];
```

How can I get a specific attribute from $model->attributes
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii model attributes are named as objects of class.
An activeRecord class you can find the model attributes by their names.

Considering you used the correct names which match the model attributes in the post, you can access them simply by using

```
$model->attname
```

Eg , a model "student" has attribute name and class sent in the post, you can access

```
$class = $model->class;
$name = $model->name;
```

If you have some post value which is not part of model (should not happen normally), you can access it as you do normally using the $_POST directive or using print_r to find all parameters if debugging.

```
print_r($_POST);
```